# Java - How to parse large int as command line argument?

Tags: java, int

I need to write a short program that works for all values of n. n is a command line argument(args[0]). The problem is Integer.parseInt doesn't work for large values such as 20000000000. What could i do to get around this problem? The program is designed to print all values that are the power of 2 until that value is >= n and n has to be argument[0].

```
public class PowerOfTwo{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int k = 1;
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    if(n < 0){
        System.out.println("");
    }else{
        for(int i=1; k <= n; i++){
            k *= 2;
            if(k <= n){
                System.out.println(k);
            }else{
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try passing the string into the BigInteger(String) constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use java.math.BigInteger or java.math.BigDecimal. These can handle numbers of any magnitude.

Your loop would then look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
    BigInteger k = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(args[0]);
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
        System.out.println("< 0");
    } else {
        while (k.compareTo(n) <= 0) {
            k = k.multiply(TWO);
            if (k.compareTo(n) <= 0) {
                System.out.println(k);
            } else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's seems a bit more complicated than what i have learned so far in my current course, but i think i can make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the maximum value you are expecting to process?

- For large numbers up to 2^63 - 1, you can use long - see more information on [data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), you'll need to change Integer.parseInt()  to Long.parseLong().
- If you genuinely need arbitrarily large numbers use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). To do this you'll also need to change your variable k to be a BigInteger and use [BigInteger.multiply()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply(java.math.BigInteger)) instead of *= and construct your variable n using [new BigInteger(String value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have no experience using BigInteger. The assignment requires it to work for ALL values of n. So BigInteger would be the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
public class PowerOfTwo{
public static void main(String[] args){
    long k = 1;

    long n = Long.parseLong("20000000000");
    BigDecimal bigDec=new BigDecimal(n);
    if(n < 0){
        System.out.println("");
    }else{
        for(long i=1; k <= bigDec.longValue(); i++){
            k *= 2;
            if(k <= n){
                System.out.println(k);
            }else{
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
2147483648
4294967296
8589934592
17179869184
```

Comment: Using long just pushes the problem up to bigger numbers.

Comment: Thanks, this does it for the values of n our code evaluation program requires :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the safest and simplest way to do this is:

```
public class ReadBigInteger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = args[0];
        if (number == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();       
        }

        System.out.println("The number: " + number);
        char [] tmp = number.toCharArray();

        int result = 0;
        int index = 1;

        for (int t = tmp.length - 1; t >= 0; t--) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(tmp[t] + "");

            int toAdd = (int) (n == 0 ? (Math.pow(10, index-1)) : (n * (Math.pow(10, index-1))));

            if (toAdd > Integer.MAX_VALUE - result) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number to large");
            }
            result += toAdd;
            index++;
        }

        System.out.println("Entered integer: " + result);
    } 
}
```

Basically read the argument as a string. Parse it in reverse order by building the integer as you go along. An exception will be thrown if the result is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`